# How can I repair a kitchen sink that is leaking from both the handle and the underneath cabinet?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, kitchen-sink

My kitchen sink is a single-handle, ball-type faucet. Lately it has been leaking from the base of the handle when the water is running, and when that happens water also drips beneath the sink.

Is it probable that replacing the [valve kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GZU9LS) and [o-rings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GZU6FC) will solve **both** issues? If there are two things going on at the same time I might just call a handyman. But I know I can replace the valve since I've done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The standard repair kit includes two small O rings (and springs) for the ball as well as two (or four) large O rings for the shaft.  You're leaking from both sets of rings I think.

I recommend that you also add a little silicone lube so the ball moves freely on the rings.  Don't use oil or vaseline; they'll dissolve the neoprene rings.

This Danco kit for Delta faucets is typical for single arm sink faucets:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Faucet-Repair-Kit-for-Delta-86970/203194028?N=5yc1vZc6ak